# How to create a Vob in base ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase, radix, cleartool, vob

I am using base ClearCase.

I want to create a Vob, with a storage location being my system hostename.

What is the process to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- declare a vob storage: see **[`mkstgloc`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkstgloc.htm)** and [About ClearCase Storages](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21147041):
  The key is to have a path that you can access through the network (an UNC path like `\\myPC\ccstg_c\vobs`, with `ccstg_c` the sharing name of a local directory under which you define your Vobs storage location)
- create your Vob (if it is a public one, you need to know the clearcase registry password, as detailed in [Set or change the ClearCase registry password](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21130852) and **[`rgy_passwd`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/rgy_passwd.htm)**)
  See **[`mkvob`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkvob.htm)**.